# Probability of zero identical events

Tags: probability

Given I have a bag of X uniquely numbered balls, and every time I pick one up, I put it back in. How many times (n), do I need to draw a ball for the probability of one or more duplicates reaches p?

I understood this problem as multiple independent events, and thus:

> *P*(*A* and *B*) = *P*(*A*) *P*(*B*)

We know that the probability of picking a duplicate is **1 / X**, which means that the probability of NOT picking a duplicate is

> **(X − 1) / X**

Now we want to know how many balls do we need to pick before there is a 1% chance of getting a duplicate.

> *P*(probability of picking 1 or more duplicate) = 0.01
>   1 − P(probability of NOT picking 1 or more duplicate) = 0.01
>   1 − ((X − 1) / X )<sup>n</sup> = 0.01
>   ((X − 1) / X )<sup>n</sup> = 0.99
>   n = *log* 0.99 / *log*((X − 1)/X)

However, someone is telling be this is wrong, and the exponent should be `(n*(n-1))/2`, instead of `n`... Which one of us is right (or both wrong?), and why?

Comment: The exact probability of having no duplicate after $n$ draws is $$\left(1-\frac1x\right)\left(1-\frac2x\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{n-1}x\right)$$ To equate this with $$\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{n(n-1)/2}$$ first, is an approximation, and second, probably requires to consider that $$x^2\gg n^3$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice: Your calculation is for the probability of picking at least one of a particular number among $n$ draws.

---

Their argument is that there are $\binom n2$ ways to select a pair among $n$ events, and the marginal probability that a particular pair is not a duplicate is $(X-1)/X$, so the probability that no pair is a duplicate should be **approximately**: $$\left(\dfrac{X-1}{X}\right)^{n(n-1)/2}$$

It is not *exactly* that, because the events are not independent, but for large $X$ and small $n$ it becomes reasonable.